# Hangfire ContinueWithJob is stuck in awaiting state, though parent job has succeeded

Tags: c#, hangfire

I have a few jobs executed one after the other via `ContinueJobWith<MyHandler>(parentJobId, x => x.DoWork())`.

However, the second job is not getting processed and always sits in `Awaiting` state:
[image: Parent is Succeeded, but job is not procssesed]

The job itself is like this:
[image: Stuck in Enqueued]

Why this can happen and where to check for resultion?

- We are using Autofac as DI container, but we have our own `JobActivator` implementation because we have to deal with multitenancy.
- We are using SQL Server 2019 for storage.
- Hangfire version is 1.7.10
- This is MVC 5 application
- I've not seen any errors/exceptions in any logs or during debugging
- After going through [this](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/issues/1035) I've added this to our Autofac registration

```
            builder.RegisterType<BackgroundJobStateChanger>()
                   .As<IBackgroundJobStateChanger>()
                   .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

This made no difference.

This is how the jobs are executed:

```
var parentJobId = _backgroundJobClient.Schedule<Handler>(h => h.ConvertCertToTraining(certId, command.SetUpOneToOneRelationship), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
var filesCopyJObId = _backgroundJobClient.ContinueJobWith<Handler>(parentJobId, h => h.CopyAttachedFiles());
_backgroundJobClient.ContinueJobWith<Handler>(filesCopyJObId, h => h.NotifyUser(command.CertificationToBeConvertedIds, _principal.GetEmail()));
```

All the parameters are either `int`, `bool` or `string`. If I enqueue the awaiting jobs by hand, they are executed without issues.

I've added Hangfire logging, but could not see any issues there: server starts, stops, jobs change status, but could not see any obvious errors there.

What other things I should consider or where/how should I debug this?

Comment: You can have some logs generated in the job so you can analyze to see what happened.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Check them. No exceptions, no other hints on what can cause that. I can see the parent job gees through stages and eventually becomes processed, but nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During the investigation, it turned out that we were replacing `JobFilterProviderCollection` with our own collection:

```
    var filterProviderCollection = new JobFilterProviderCollection
    {
        new MyFilterProvider(...)
    };
    var backgroundJobClient = new BackgroundJobClient(JobStorage.Current, filterProviderCollection);
```

`MyFilterProvider` looked like this:

```
    public IEnumerable<JobFilter> GetFilters(Job job)
    {
        return new JobFilter[]
        {
             new JobFilter(new HangfireTenantFilter(_tenantDetail, _principal), JobFilterScope.Global,  null),
             new JobFilter(new HangfireFunctionalityFilter(_functionalityFilter), JobFilterScope.Global, null),
        };
    }
```

It turned out that code that was doing work on Continuation only took filters from this filter collection and `ContinuationsSupportAttribute` was not executed there in the right time. So re-adding default Hangfire filters from `GlobalJobFilters.Filters` fixed the situation:

```
    public IEnumerable<JobFilter> GetFilters(Job job)
    {
        var customFilters = new List<JobFilter>()
        {
             new JobFilter(new HangfireTenantFilter(_tenantDetail, _principal), JobFilterScope.Global,  null),
             new JobFilter(new HangfireFunctionalityFilter(_functionalityFilter), JobFilterScope.Global, null),
        };
        customFilters.AddRange(GlobalJobFilters.Filters);

        return customFilters;
    }
```

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out.

Comment: @Jawad Thanks for taking time to respond, appreciate it! Enjoy the bounty :-)

Comment: Thanks. I had a similar issue. I had a filter where I returned a new JobFilter array with my own filter. I guess the ContinuationFilter was missing then and no continuation was executed. Now I create a copy of the global filter list, add my own filter and return the whole collection. Thanks again. This was a lifesaver.

Answer (score 8):

From the looks of it, the first job with ID `216348` completed successfully but your second job with ID `216349` is waiting on the parent ID of `216347`. According to Hangfire documentation and experience, the parentID should be of the job that you are waiting to finish before executing the second job.

According to [Hangfire documentation on ContinueJobWith](https://www.hangfire.io/), "*Continuations are executed when its parent job **has been finished***". From your screenshots, it is not clear whats going on with JobID: `216347`. Once this job, `216347` completes, job with ID `216349` should kick off. If you are expecting `216349` to start after `216348` finishes, check your code and make sure correct ParentID is passed to the second job.

---

> **Update**

Based [on this thread](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/issues/1206), add the `ContinuationsSupportAttribute` to `GlobalJobFilters.Filter` where you configure Hangfire service. This should make your Hangfire instance aware of continuation jobs.

```
GlobalJobFilters.Filters.Add(new ContinuationsSupportAttribute());
```

Comment: Double checked that - it is not that. Added a code snippet of how I initiate the jobs.

Comment: @trailmax see update to my post. Hopefully that will resolve your issue

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I've tried that before and it made no difference (tried it again just now and no change there :-/). Also, as far as I can see in Hangfire's source, that filter is now [included by default](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/blob/88af1e4c98fe1c1a24c21a99d350bc7f1ed7d575/src/Hangfire.Core/GlobalJobFilters.cs#L37) And I do see it included when examine `GlobalJobFilters.Filters` in debuging.

Comment: @trailmax I think this may be a bug but try this in debug. Execute each of the three statements and see what parentId you get for each. Somehow it seems like wrong parentId is going to the third statement

Comment: I've copied `ContinuationsSupportAttribute` into my project and stepped through it, turned out `Continuation` data is not added to the parent job, so once it is `Succeeded`, it does not have any info to trigger any continuations. I'm trying to figure out why this data is not added.

Comment: @trailmax does adding `JobContinuationOptions.OnlyOnSucceededState` to your call makes any difference?

Comment: Sorry for being slow responder - this problem has gone to a background with very low priority. I'll eventually figure it out and will update you on the what is happening.

Comment: I've found the solution to the problem - see my answer. Thank you for pushing me into the right direction of `ContinuationsSupportAttribute`.